# Connect to Git hosted on VSTS on Mac using XCode

Tags: xcode, git, azure-devops, xcode9

I am trying to connect to a Git repository hosted on VSTS from a Mac machine in Xcode 9. I tried cloning the project using Xcode but it gives me authentication failure error.

I don't get this problem in Windows. I have also tried creating a Personal Access Token in my VSTS account profile and used the secret key but that too doesn't work.

References:-

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/share-your-code-in-git-xcode
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/set-up-credential-managers

Am I missing on something? Please let me know if I can provide more details.

**Update**

Somehow I can clone the project to my local using Visual Studio on Mac after generating Git credentials through VSTS. Strange that it does not work with the XCode.

Comment: List the steps you took in following the Share Your Code in Git Xcode article you linked to. At what step do you get the error? You mentioned cloning the project, but the article says you need to create a local git repo for your Xcode project, create a VSTS repo, create a remote repo in Xcode, and push to the remote repo. Have you done all that? Listing every step you took and providing more detail about the authentication failure error will improve your chances of getting a solution.

Comment: Consider using ssh instead of a personal access token.

Comment: When you checkout your VSTS git repo, does xcode ask you to input username and password? And for the PAT(Personal Access Token), did you created with full scopes?

Comment: @MarkSzymczyk I get the error while trying to get an existing project from the remote repo. There is no need for me to create a local repo and push to remote as of now though.

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT Yes it gives a prompt. I tried using my AD login as well as PAT. I was able to clone the project to my local using Visual Studio on Mac after generating Git credentials through VSTS but no luck with XCode.

Comment: @SouvikGhosh What if you clear the stored credential (as the link 
 shows https://confluence.bethel.edu/display/ITSKB/Clearing+Saved+Credentials+in+Mac+OS), and then clone again to only input PAT for password (leave username empty)?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT I couldn't clear any key chain as there were no such values tired for Xcode. What I did was use the PAT in the username and password both. It took then took me to Microsoft SSO and there I had to login, I again got a prompt for Microsoft SSO and successfully able to get the code. So the key solution for me I guess is to use the PAT in both username and password prompt of the Git in XCode.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used VSTS, but this answer shows how to connect to a remote repository that's not a GitHub repository in Xcode 9. Start by opening the source control navigator by choosing View > Navigators > Show Source Control Navigator.

[image]

The next step is to add a remote branch for your VSTS repository. Select the Remotes folder in the source control navigator, right-click, and choose Add Existing Remote.
[image]

Enter the URL of your VSTS repo in the Location text field. Click the Add button to finish adding the remote repository.

At this point you have an empty remote repository in Xcode. The last step is to push your local Xcode repository to the remote repository. Choose Source Control > Push in Xcode to do the push.

You will be asked for a username and password for the remote repository. According to the first link from Microsoft in your question, you should enter your VSTS username as the username and the personal access token as the password.